# how to replace instance variable with local variable in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the gem [rails_best_practices](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices) installed and I am wondering how to replace my instance variables with local variables?

I have tried using `:locals => { :department_category => @department_category }` but I am not exactly sure if that is the part of my code that is even giving the error

The problem line is the following:

#### _category_edit.haml

```
%a.black-link.bold{href: admin_content_departments_category_edit_path(params[:department_id], params[:child_department_id], category.id), :class => ("active" if @department_category.id == category.id)}
  #{category.title}
```

Why does this code give an error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `replace instance variable with local variable`

Comment: *Why does this code give an error?* What is the error you are mentioning?

Comment: That is what I am unsure of but I seem to get them in all of my partials, I am trying to refactor everything to go by "best practice" guidelines found [here](https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/24/replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable/)

Comment: You are doing it right. Use `department_category` in the views which is passed as *local variable*

Comment: Now I understood what this **"replace instance variable with local variable"** mean by. You should replace `@department_category` with `department_category` in `_category_edit.haml`. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> replace instance variable with local variable

I believe you are rendering `_category_edit.haml` with `:locals => { :department_category => @department_category }`, then you should use `department_category`(*local variable*) instead of `@department_category`(*instance variable*) in `_category_edit.haml`

```
#_category_edit.haml
%a.black-link.bold{href: admin_content_departments_category_edit_path(params[:department_id], params[:child_department_id], category.id), :class => ("active" if department_category.id == category.id)}
  #{category.title}
```